# Placing relative pos. div below absolute pos. div

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

**Hi,**

I know this question is very similar to others, and i've checked them but I can't make it work and my problem is a little different.

First I have a `block` with **100%** height of viewport. It must be positioned `absolute` otherwise I can't make it 100% of the viewport.
Then there is a block which height will be determined by it's content.
Now the problem is that the last block won't be placed below the absolute one because they will overlap because the first one has `position: absolute`. I can make it work by relatively positioning the second, but I want to have more than 1 block like the second below.

**This is what I want**

```
 ______________________
|                      |
|     height:100%;     | position:absolute;
|______________________|
|                      |
|   SometextSometext   | height:auto;
|   SometextSometext   | /*determined by it's content*/
|______________________|
|                      |
|   SometextSometext   | height:auto;
|   SometextSometext   | /*determined by it's content*/
|______________________|
```

Comment: Try replacing your height 100% and position absolute both just with "height: 100vh;"

Comment: But with this unit remember about http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Michal

Answer (score 1):

Remove the positioning from the first `div` an set its height to `100vh`

[**More on `vh` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

> **vh** 1/100th of the height of the viewport.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
section:first-of-type {
  height: 100vh
}
section {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content
  <br />content
  <br />content
  <br />content
  <br />content
  <br />
</div>
```